# Good uses of static classes for interfaces in C++

Tags: c++, interface

I am creating an API for some driver that only changes some HW registers.  I have thought to do this using a pure static class, like so.

```
class RegisterStaticClass
 {
 public:
 static bool setRegister1( const uint8_t aValue1, const uint8_t aValue2 = 0 );
 static bool setRegister2( const uint8_t aValue1, const uint8_t aValue2 = 0 );
};
```

I was wondering if this is the best approach, I thought the calling code now has an easier time as it must only do:

```
 RegisterStaticClass::setRegister1( 23, 45);
```

Are there any downsides of this approach?

Comment: Only static classes can be substituted by namespace.

Answer (score 6):

You effectively implemented a namespace. Just using a namespace instead will give you the same syntax with better readability and you do not need to worry about someone trying to create an object of that class.

The way to make private functions or data members in a namespace is to use an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace RegisterStaticClass{
    //public:
    bool setRegister1( const uint8_t aValue1, const uint8_t aValue2 = 0 );
    //private:
    namespace{
        //accessible only within this namespace
        bool setRegister2( const uint8_t aValue1, const uint8_t aValue2 = 0 );
    }
}
//usage:
RegisterStaticClass::setRegister1( 23, 45);
RegisterStaticClass::setRegister2( 23, 45); //error
```

Comment: OK thanks, namespaces seems the best way to do this.  Are there any savings in terms of performance or memory?

Comment: @user1876942 Unlikely. If you have something like `{char c1; int i; char c2;}` the compiler will pad both `char`s to the size of an `int` (the one at the end for the case you make arrays of objects). The compiler is not allowed to change the order to `{char c1; char c2; int i;}` in a `class` or `struct`, but in a `namespace` it can. For functions I would not expect any difference in the generated code.

Comment: For regular classes/functions I agree. But a class template with static member functions can be more conveniently specialized than a namespace of function templates.